# Can a session variable be get and appended to a URL (PHP)

Tags: php, url, url-routing, session-variables, session-cookies

I had set and get the current page URL in a variable using session.

```
                $currentURL = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
                $currentPageSplit = explode('?___',$currentURL);
                $currentPageURL = $currentPageSplit[0]; 

                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setCurrentPage($currentPageURL);
                session_start(); 
                $curr = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getCurrentPage();
```

Now that I want this variable $curr to be appended to another URL used for switching from one page to another.

```
<a class="desktop" href="<?php echo $curr.'/?switch-view=desktop';?>">View desktop version</a>
```

I am unable to do this. Can someone tell if this syntax is right or what else could be done.

Thanks in adv

Comment: I have no idea what class of `Mage` is, but I don't see any session variables used here. If you want session variable to be appended to url then just `?my_session_var=<?php echo $_SESSION['some_var'] ?>` and read it later with `$_GET['my_session_var']`. It is serious security issue though.

Answer (score 0):

yes possible.

```
   <?php 
   $sample=$_SESSION['alpha']; 
   echo '<a href="sample/sample.php?id='.$sample.'">click</a>';
  ?> `
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

**To use the url in same page where you declare your session variable**

```
<?php
$view = 'switch-view=desktop';
$_SESSION['view'] = $view;
$curr =  $_SESSION['view'];
?>
<a class="desktop" href="<?php echo $curr;?>">View desktop version</a>
```

**If you need to use the session in another page**

```
<?php
session_start();
$curr =  $_SESSION['view'];
?>
<a class="desktop" href="<?php echo $curr;?>">View desktop version</a>
```